# Revoke token in LinkedIn Oauth2 rest api

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using the linkedin rest api.
The browser that will be used by the users will have different users logging in
on it so i need to be able to invalidate the access token.
I know with the javascript api i can use IN.User.logout(); and it works.

What is the equivalent in the OAuth2 linkedin rest api ?